# Value notation for this ASN.1 Schema

Tags: asn.1

having a bit of a struggle using ASN.1, been googling a bit round looking for answers but everything I findf is related to the "template" side of things, not the values. I have the following ASN.1 schema.

```
FooProtocol DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

    FooQuestion ::= SEQUENCE {
        rows INTEGER,
        cols INTEGER,
        lines GameLines
    }

GameLines ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE (1..100)) OF Item

Item ::= SEQUENCE {
line           UTF8String

}
END
```

And I'm trying to write the following values to pass trough the schema :

```
myQuestion FooQuestion ::= 
{
    rows 5,
    cols 4,
    lines {"test"} // <- Wrong
}
```

How would I go about populating the GameLines which are a sequence of items?
Is there any good rescources on this out there? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in your particular case should be:

```
myQuestion FooQuestion ::= 
{
    rows 5,
    cols 4,
    lines {{line "test1"}, {line "test2"}}
}
```

The syntax for SEQUENCE OF is: write the value notation of each item separated by commas, and put everything between curly braces.

On a side note, it is better to use automatic tags, so you have to change the module header like this:
`FooProtocol DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN`.